# For the current observation value, how to find total number of previous observations and time since last observation?

Tags: r, dataframe, time, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe which records observations across a 31 year time series in 6 month steps at 3806 individual sites. Observations are patchy and not consistent across time steps or sites. All missing values are NaN. I want to know, for each site at each six month time step: 1) the total number of observations that came before that one, and 2) the time since the last observation.

**Here is sample data:**

```
Site <- seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1)
T1 <- c(1, NaN, 2, 3, NaN, 1, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1)  
T2 <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, NaN, NaN)   
T3 <- c(1, 2, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1, NaN, 2, NaN, 1)   
T4 <- c(NaN, 1, 2, 3, NaN, 1, 1, 1, 2, NaN)   
all <- data.frame(Site, T1, T2, T3, T4)  
colnames(all) <- c("Site", "1992", "1992.5", "1993", "1993.5")

head(all)
```

| Site | 1992 | 1992.5 | 1993 | 1993.5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | NaN |
| 2 | NaN | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | NaN | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 | NaN | 3 |
| 5 | NaN | 1 | NaN | NaN |
| 6 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

**I tried first converting to long format:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_long <- gather(all, "1992":"1993.5", key = Date, value = Observation, na.rm = FALSE)
```

Then using tally, but if I want to do it at each year I then get just n = 1 for each Site and Year:

```
all_long %>% 
  group_by(Site, Date) %>% 
  tally()
```

Expected output in long format would be something like:

At Site 1 in 1993.5, there are 3 observations before that one (TotalObs), and there was an observation in the previous time step so the time since last observation should only be 1 time step (i.e. 6 months) (TimeSinceObs).

| Site | Date | Observation | TotalObs | TimeSinceObs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1993.5 | NaN | 3 | 1 |

I don't care about the actual values, just how many times observations have been recorded and when the last one was at each time step. If anyone can help I'd be super grateful!

Comment: What is `ReefID`? Also please share the expected output

Comment: Hi @Sotos, sorry about that, it was a mistake. I've corrected the text and added an expected output.

Comment: What would the result be for `site 2` and `site 5`?

Comment: In 1993.5: Site 2 TotalObs = 2, TimeSinceObs = 1; In 1993.5 Site 5 TotalObs = 1, TimeSinceObs = 2. 

Each time step/column would be counted as 1, so if there is an observation in the column before then Time Since Obs is 1, if only 2 columns before then 2, etc. 

For TotalObs, it's the total number of observations before that one. Does that make sense? 

Thanks so much :)

Comment: I m not sure I understood 100% but I added an answer. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way given that your origin is always `1993.5`,

```
data.frame(Site = all$Site, 
           Date = names(all)[ncol(all)], 
           Observation = all[[ncol(all)]], 
           TotalObs = rowSums(!is.na(all[-c(1, ncol(all))])), 
           TimeSinceObs = ncol(all[-1]) - max.col(!is.na(all[-c(1, ncol(all))]), ties.method = 'last'))

   Site   Date Observation TotalObs TimeSinceObs
1     1 1993.5         NaN        3            1
2     2 1993.5           1        2            1
3     3 1993.5           2        2            2
4     4 1993.5           3        2            2
5     5 1993.5         NaN        1            2
6     6 1993.5           1        3            1
7     7 1993.5           1        1            2
8     8 1993.5           1        2            1
9     9 1993.5           2        0            1
10   10 1993.5         NaN        2            1
```

Comment: Hi @Sotos, thanks so much for your answer. That does work perfectly for the original dataframe and for Year 1993.5, however I wanted to calculate the TotalObs and TimeSinceObs for each individual Date + Site combination. I converted to long format first so that I could then just have one column with TotalObs and TimeSinceObs for each Site (1:3806 in my actual data) and Date (1992 to 2021 by 6 month time steps in my actual data). Sorry if that wasn't clear, but I appreciate your help! I suppose I could run a loop with the code you wrote to cycle through each column and then join them all?